# Use array of objects in another class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

This imports the text from a file and creates an array of objects of the type **foe**

```
class cmdquest{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

            //Importing foes.txt to create objects of foes
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File("foes.txt");
            Scanner imp = new Scanner(file);  
            foe foes[] = new foe[100];
            for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
                foes[i]=foe.leDados(imp);
            }
}
```

In another class I've got this, but it does not work

```
static void db(){
    for(int a=0; a<3; a++){
        System.out.print(cmdquest.foes[a].name + "\t");
    }
    System.out.print("*Press Enter to go back to the main menu*");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        kb.nextLine();

        Menu.show_menu();
}
```

This is my class **foe** with everything declared, including name:

```
class foe{
    String name;
    int hp;
    int str;
    int def;

    foe(String n, int h, int s, int d) {
    name = n;
    hp = h;
    str = s;
    def= d;
    }

    static foe leDados(Scanner imp){
            String foe_name = imp.next();
            int foe_hp = imp.nextInt();
            int foe_str = imp.nextInt();
            int foe_def = imp.nextInt();
        return new foe(foe_name, foe_hp, foe_str, foe_def);
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when compiling:

```
   cmdquest.java:186: error: cannot find symbol
                            System.out.print(cmdquest.foes[a].name + "\t");
                                                             ^
      symbol:   variable foes
      location: class cmdquest
    1 error
```

Comment: You should declare `foe foes[] = new foe[100];` outside of your `main` class.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelFernando read the link mentioned in my answer, coding best practice, you need it. and try to use modifers both with fields and methods.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should work.

```
class cmdquest{
    public foe foes[] = new foe[100];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        //Importing foes.txt to create objects of foes
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("foes.txt");
        Scanner imp = new Scanner(file);  

        for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
            foes[i]=foe.leDados(imp);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem.
I added "static" like this "static foe foes[] = new foe[100];"

Comment: -1 How does this work?  Is foes public, static? Is that the default?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelFernando Yes, you had to add that, so the answer is not correct

Answer (score 1):

In your code the problem is you are trying to access an object which not exists in the class

```
System.out.print(cmdquest.foes[a].name + "\t");
```

this line says that cmdquest has a public array field names as foes. But there is no field in your class.

In your class

```
class cmdquest{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

            //Importing foes.txt to create objects of foes
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File("foes.txt");
            Scanner imp = new Scanner(file);  
            foe foes[] = new foe[100];
            for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
                foes[i]=foe.leDados(imp);
            }
    }
}
```

foes is a local field that has no existance outside main method.so you cann't refere foes outside main method.

To access foes from outside you have to make foes as global variable in cmdquest class and have to provide modifier depend upon your requirment.

```
public class cmdquest{

    public foe foes[] = new foe[100];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

            //Importing foes.txt to create objects of foes
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File("foes.txt");
            Scanner imp = new Scanner(file);  
            for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
                foes[i]=foe.leDados(imp);
            }
   }
}
```

In case you want to directly access the foes object without creating cmdquest object then make foes object as static

```
 public static foe foes[] = new foe[100];
```

This is the solution of your problem. But this is not the end before coding in java you must have to follow some guideline or best practices so that you can write better code and less errorpron. So for that read this artical : 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/most-useful-java-best-practice-quotes-java-developers/

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need to make your code work would be to store foes as a static property on `cmdquest`

```
class cmdquest{

    public static foes foes[];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

            //Importing foes.txt to create objects of foes
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File("foes.txt");
            Scanner imp = new Scanner(file);  
            for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
                foes[i]=foe.leDados(imp);
   }
}
```

But it is bad practice to have mutable static properties, because they are essentially global variables. You should just have a method that returns `foe[]`

```
class foe{
    String name;
    int hp;
    int str;
    int def;

    foe(String n, int h, int s, int d) {
      name = n;
      hp = h;
      str = s;
      def= d;
    }

    private static foe leDados(Scanner imp){
            String foe_name = imp.next();
            int foe_hp = imp.nextInt();
            int foe_str = imp.nextInt();
            int foe_def = imp.nextInt();
        return new foe(foe_name, foe_hp, foe_str, foe_def);
    }

    public static foe[] getFoes() {

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("foes.txt");
        Scanner imp = new Scanner(file);  

        foe foes[] = new foe[100];
        for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
            foes[i] = foe.leDados(imp);
        }
        return foes;
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
static void db(){
    foes[] foes = foe.getFoes();
    for(int a=0; a<3; a++){
        System.out.print(cmdquest.foes[a].name + "\t");
    }
```